# Wise to switch from Sony to Canon considering I have a decent amount of lenses?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, sony

I've been trying to decide on this for a while now and I need to decide before tomorrow because of a great deal which ends by then.

Current situation: I'm currently shooting with a Sony a580 and the following gear:

Sigma 10-20/4-5.6, Sony 35/1.8, Tamron 17-50/2.8, Konica Minolta 50/1.7, Sigma 70/2.8 Macro, Konica Minolta 75-300/4-5.6 (Kit lens, sucks) and a HVL-F42AM (flash)

I've been worried about the A mount future for some time now. It's been a while since Sony announced any A mount lenses. It seems like only the E mount is getting any attention from Sony. On top of this, I'm a student and I basically rely on the second hand market which isn't that good when you're shooting Sony in Sweden.

This made me think about Canon and how if I'm gonna switch, I probably gonna do it ASAP. A deal came up on a major Swedish site. A Canon 6D + 50/1.4 + 32GB Sandisk Extreme + iPad Mini 16GB for $2.360/1.731€. I have no need for an iPad and would sell it if I got the deal. Remember that this is in Sweden so the deal might not sound "as good" to you if you're American example but the second best price is $2.400 for body only here in Sweden so it's pretty sick.

However, would it be a wise choice? It would take some time to get the range of lenses I have today... I would be stuck on only the 50/1.4 for a while...

I mainly shoot macro and portraits. My goal would be to get a 28-75/2.8 (Tamron perhaps) and then get some sort of macro lens. Maybe save my Sony gear during the time I'm low on Canon lenses?

On the other side... probably getting a Tamron/Sigma 70-200/2.8 for Sony. But that would probably seal the deal and I'd stay on Sony forever. If it turns out the let the A mount "fade away" (=Not announcing any more cameras or lenses) I'm stuck in a dead system and if my camera would break down a couple of years down the road my only alternative would be a couple of years old second hand camera...

I would love any opinion you might have as I struggle to come to a decision. There's a lot of things I would miss in the Sony system (In-house IS, Tilt screen, etc.).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't get too worried about the particular deal you've found. The Canon 6D is almost two years into its product life cycle, and while this may be the best deal you've seen so far, it's unlikely to be the last.

Comment: What is it you're finding limiting about your current gear? Swapping the A580 for a 6D definitely isn't a straight swap as you're moving from upper-entry level APS-C camera to full-frame.

Comment: I've been longing for a FF for quite some time. This is my third camera (a100 -> a550 -> a580) so I just thought that if I'd switch again, it'd be for a FF. I'm looking for better AF, more DoF (as I shoot alot of portraits) and better build quality in a new camera. The focus points of the 6D is a little bit disappointing but other than that I think it's a great camera.

Comment: If you want more (greater) depth of field, then you want a smaller sensor, not a bigger one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. Shallower DoF is what I meant.

Comment: I think you're making a mistake by saying that the system is obsolete if the mount isn't supported any more. Sure, they won't be making new lenses for it, but what do you care? You already have good lenses, everything you need. You can use that camera for the next twenty years till it stops working, so why not do that? There is no clear advantage to switching and buying all your stuff again. You already have a good camera - a Canon won't be better simply because you can get lenses for it - you don't need lenses, right?

Comment: Could you better explain why are you avoiding the current Sony A-Mount FF, the A99?  For what it's worth, Sony won't abandon the A mount.  If they do, it will signal they might abandon any of their other mounts in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Is it wise? Well, probably the *wise* thing to do is to sell all of your electronics, camera gear included, and live a quiet life of mediation and peace.

Or, is it a smart investment? Again, neither of these options is really the best. Better to sell it all and pick up a nice low-overhead index fund.

But, photography is an art. Art is not wise (even if it can reflect wisdom). And it's not an investment (even though it takes money). You should follow your passion, here. From that perspective, I think you should decide how much you personally weigh the following things:

- Is the worry of obsolescence or abandonment your main concern? If so, my advice is to let it go. Enjoy what you have — you say there are a lot of key features you like and would miss, and I bet there are others that haven't even occurred to you — and in the event Sony ditches the system entirely or doesn't grow it to meet your future photography... make the change then. For now, you've got the lenses, and everything you need.
- If it's about losing money because the value of the gear will go down.... again, I suggest letting this go. There are a [few things in photography](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2009/05/why-it-has-to-be-a-leica.html) that you can buy and which will hold monetary value, but in the most part, the value is in the photographs you can extract from the equipment. It's true that you may be able to get less out of reselling your gear in the future, but in the meantime, you'll get more *use*.
- If it's because the desired new platform provides something you really are interested in in order to grow your photography, on the other hand, I suggest seizing the day — life is short, and no point wondering if you would be happier when you can just do it.
- *But*, if you have the sort of personality which is attracted to new and shiny gadgets, and find yourself often dissatisfied with a purchase because something else came out with better specs... if, in general, you suffer from "grass-is-greener" syndrome... well, then, you probably won't really be happy with whatever you do. (Hmmmm; in this case maybe the idea of selling everything and moving to the mountains isn't so bad after all.)

Comment: Great comment and some good insight! I do think there's a part of every point. I really do think I would get a creativity boost from getting a new camera. Also, I think that it would be wiser in the long run as Canon offers some lenses Sony doesn't (85/1.8, 135/2, 17-40) and they're possible to get on the aftermarket! I really look forward to building up a new lens collection with greater possibilities (as it's quite limited with Sony).

But then again. It's damn expensive. I would be limited for a while, not sure if I could get all my Sony gear sold, etc. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't as big of a deal to switch as you think.  It is fairly common when switching systems to sell off the old system and re-buy lenses in the new system.  You do take a hit when off-loading the old lenses for the old system, but it still lets you get back up and running on the new system pretty quickly.  It isn't trivial, but it also isn't too bad, even on a limited budget.

As far as if the trade off between your current camera and line up of lenses is better than the 6D for the amount you'd be putting in to it, that's more opinion based, so only you can really decide, but if you'd like to have more of a discussion on it, you have sufficient reputation to join [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) where we can handle things that are more opinion or discussion related.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you're a student. I'll assume budget is a factor. With that in mind, have you considered cost of switching to Canon i.e. assume you sell off all your existing Sony gear at a fair price, will the proceeds be enough to buy equivalent lens for the type of photography you do. After all, the last thing you need is to switch and not be able to do the photography you want.

Speaking as a 5-year old Nikon to Canon switcher, I am very pleased with Canon though I had to save to afford the L lenses I wanted ("needed") for my photography.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 

It is true that I wouldn't be able to get the same lenses (or equivalent) if I switched to Canon. My plan would be to save up for a 24-70/2.8 and then move on to a macro lens. 

I know it would be expensive and that I would be limited for a period of time (That's why I would probably wait to sell my Sony gear. Like, sell my macro lens when I have one for the Canon etc.). My 35/1.8 is on the a580 most of the time (like 80%?) so I don't think it would be too bad. Also, the Tamron 28-75/2.8 doesn't seem that expensive so I might get one of those too for an allround.